# iframe embedded in containers conflicts with vertical scroll in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm new in sencha touch. I have a list of video urls extracted from a json file. I displayed this urls using an iframe. However whenever I clicked one iframe and scroll it vertically, the whole page / window scrolls including the tab buttons and the status bar.

I already tried embedding the iframe tag inside div but this doesn't solve the problem.